# Python Shift by trading date

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hi I created a daily price list of a stock and now I need to insert another column for 14days return. Currently I have the following:

```
data["2W-Chg"]=stock_store['Adj Close'] - stock_store['Adj Close'].shift(14)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5xEjp.png)

but when checking the shifting, it had actual shift more than 14 days (eg. Today: 6/23/2021, Shifted to: 6/2/2021). The correct shifting date that I'm looking for should be 6/09/2021.
Is there anyway to shift base on trading date instead by row?

Thanks

JC

Comment: `shift` has a `freq` parameter, did you look into that? e.g., `.shift(14, freq="B")`.

Comment: ...and please don't post images; text is needed. Along with a [mcve] of course.

Comment: Thanks Mustafa, I had changed to:
     data["2W-Chg"]=stock_store['Adj Close'] - stock_store['Adj Close'].shift(periods=14, freq='B')

But it throws error "NotImplementedError: Not supported for type RangeIndex".

Comment: I see, then you better set your `Date` as the index and please try again: `stock_store = stock_store.set_index("Date")` because `shift` looks at the index, not any datetime column automatically.

Comment: Thanks Mustafa, I had set the index when reading the csv file using:
     stock_store=pd.read_csv('abc.csv',parse_dates=['Date'], index_col=['Date']) 

Also I had tried the following but it doesn't work as it still shifting based on rows but not Business Day:
.shift(14, freq="B")

But when I change to D (Calendar day frequency), then it works correctly:
.shift(14, freq="D")

Thanks so much for your help Mustafa.

Comment: I was trying to select your feedback as answer, but somehow after the comments, the answer option is gone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) has a parameter called `freq` that, when set, shifts the *index* of the data according to the given frequency instead of ignoring the time relation. So you can first set your data's index as the `date` column and then `shift` with your desired frequency:

```
# or you can set it when reading CSV, as you mentioned in the comments
stock_store = stock_store.set_index("Date")

# using `D` as the daily frequenct (as you mentioned in comments)
data["2W-Chg"] = stock_store["Adj Close"] - stock_store["Adj Close"].shift(14, freq="D")
```

Comment: Thanks Mustafa. 
Just one more quick question, if the shifted date do not exist, is it possible to auto shift to prevous available day?

Comment: @user125104 Oh, that's an interesting case... I came up with `df.shift(14, freq="D").reindex(df.index).ffill().dropna()` which shifts as before but then reindexes the frame with the original's index. After this `NaN` rows will appear if a shifted date doesn't exist. Then we forward fill the data with `ffill` which carries last preivous available data onwards. Lastly we drop the `NaN`s that appeared at the very begining (and so couldn't be filled & we don't need anyway) with `dropna`. But not sure if this modification corresponds to what you said... If not, I think you can ask a new question...